Unable to update a course by its id using mongoDB and mongoose in noddejs
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-exercise")
.then( ()=> console.log("Connected to MongoDB..."))
.catch(err => console.error("Failed to connect to db...",err));

Below is the course schema and model
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    author:String,
    tags:[String],
    date:Date,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price:Number
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);

here is the function to get the list of courses based on certain criteria.
async function getCourses() {
    return await Course
    .find({isPublished:true})
    .or([
        {price : {$gte: 15}},
        {name : /.*by.*/}
        ])
    .sort('-price')
    .select('name author price')
};

here is the function to update the course author of a particular course by its id but its failing and replying course not found
async function updateCourse(id) {
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    console.log('checking..');
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    console.log('Invalid ID format');
    return;
}
    try {
        const course = await Course.findById(id);
        if (!course) {
            console.log('Course not found');
            return;
        }

        course.isPublished = false;
        course.author = 'Manish';

        const result = await course.save();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating the course:', error);
    }
}

course id i'm trying to update and similarly other ids that exist in DB but its not working. But when querying the DB the same id appearing.
async function run() {
    const courses = await getCourses();
    console.log("List of courses \n" ,courses);
    
}
updateCourse('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777');

here is the output of the querying DB
List of courses
 [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777'),
    name: 'Node.js Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('5a6900fff467be65019a9001'),
    name: 'Angular Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e'),
    name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb'),
    name: 'Node.js Course by Jack',
    author: 'Jack',
    price: 12
  }
]

and here is is the update output
checking..
Connected to MongoDB...
Course not found
I have tried this solution to find the course by its name and its working.
async function testQuery() {
    const course = await Course.findOne({ name: 'React Course' });
    console.log('Course found by name:', course);
}

debugQuery();

what could be the potential reason that it's not updating the course or is there something wrong in my approach?

The problem is that your schema doesn't have _id: String so mongoose doesn't recognize it and by default thinks _id is an ObjectId not a string.
Just change your schema like this and it should work
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  author: String,
  tags: [String],
  date: Date,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number
});


This may be a problem with not awaiting the async function updateCourse.
I put the above code in a single file, but modified the run function to also include and await the updateCourse call, and then explicitly exit, like so:
async function run() {
    const courses = await getCourses();
    console.log("List of courses \n" ,courses);
    await updateCourse('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777');
    process.exit();
}

run();

I inserted the sample documents provided, but set isPublished:true on each.  Executing that file produced:
Connected to MongoDB...
List of courses
 [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777"),
    name: 'Node.js Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("5a6900fff467be65019a9001"),
    name: 'Angular Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e"),
    name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb"),
    name: 'Node.js Course by Jack',
    author: 'Jack',
    price: 12
  }
]
checking..
{
  tags: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777"),
  name: 'Node.js Course',
  author: 'Manish',
  price: 20,
  isPublished: false,
  __v: 1
}

